# Why does ansible jump from ubuntu user to root between two tasks?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to move a file using `ansible`.

```
- block:
    - name: Copy bin directory with owner and permission
      copy:
        src: ~/bin
        dest: /usr/local
        owner: ubuntu
        group: ubuntu
        mode: '0774'
    - name: Delete origin directory
      file:
        path: ~/bin
        state: absent
```

However, when executing this code, the bin folder gets correctly copied, but not deleted. So I thought: Well, maybe it's because `ansible` tries do delete the file in `root`, but why can it resolve `src` correctly in `copy`?

I then added this before the other two tasks:

```
- name: Creating an empty file
  file:
    path: "~/test42"
    state: touch
```

which indeed created a file at `./root/test42`. Now I am wondering why `~` one time was evaluated to ubuntu's home and one time as root's and how I can work around that.

If there is a more elegant solution to move files using `ansible` I am also open for that, but it looked like there is no inbuilt method for moving files.

Comment: yes, for moving files, in my experience, the most simplest solution is to simply use the command 'mv'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `src` used by `copy` is [local by default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-src); it will be evaluated on the controller as the user that is running `ansible-playbook` unless you specify `remote_src: true`. The `path` argument to `file` is always remote, and is evaluated on the target as the user that the module runs as.